# Dynamically scroll another element when another scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have an odd situation. Look at this image:

[image]

I have that ruler along the top. I don't want it to scroll off when I scroll the content vertically, so I put it outside the scrolling container. But now it doesn't scroll horizontally either. I need to scroll that horizontally in sync with the content container's scrollbar when the content is scrolled.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please show your ("[MCVE]") HTML, CSS and JavaScript in order that we can reproduce your problem and so provide useful answers, rather than guesses apropos of nothing. It might also be worth reading through the "[ask]" guidance, to refresh yourself on what we expect of a question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This plain javascript function picks up the `.scrollLeft` value of the `#content` and reproduces it on the `#ruler`'s `.scrollLeft`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n55d39cg/7/)

```js
document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
var elmnt2 = document.getElementById("ruler");

elmnt2.scrollLeft = elmnt.scrollLeft;

}
```

```css
#ruler {
  background: skyblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {  
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div id=ruler>1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..1..2..3..4..5</div>
<div id=content>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Really clean answer. However, this only works if the element that listens to the scroll is actually scrolling. A fixed container wont trigger the scroll event.